# Docker: Pull from docker hub, doesn't download any files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It's my second day playing with docker, I'm trying to make a simple django web server with docker. So basically I created a `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files in my directory, I have my `docker-compose.yml` set to :

```
version: '3'
    services:
      web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
        volumes:
          - .:/app
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        env_file:
          - ./env.dev
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to push these files into docker hub (repository) as I think, and then to pull them from the repo. So basically I open the terminal and launch these commands:

```
docker images
docker tag ID docker_username/repo_name:firsttry
docker push docker_username/repo_name
```

After pushing I can see that I have a repository in hub with some type of image history, so now I'm trying to pull the data to my local pc.
My commands:

```
cd some_directory
docker pull dziugasiot/wintekaiot:firsttry
```

And the response I get is:

```
firsttry: Pulling from dziugasiot/wintekaiot
Digest: sha256:477a0bb335f841875d43f0f5717c0416a500989f280112c36b613aa97d82157e
Status: Image is up to date for dziugasiot/wintekaiot:firsttry
docker.io/dziugasiot/wintekaiot:firsttry
```

The directory is empty, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What directory is empty? Docker doesn't put the images in your working directory.

Comment: The directory which I'm trying to pull the files to, is not my working directory.

Comment: Again, then, *what* directory is empty? If you mean `some_directory`, that *is* your current working directory.

Comment: I just created an empty directory with mkdir, and then tried to pull the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing wrong but thinking wrong.

1. Docker push , send image to dockerhub
2. Docker pull, download your image to a docker folder in your system, not to the directory you are in. you can see your pulled image with command:  `docker images` (show you a list)
3. having your pulled image downloaded you can use it from any directory running the command: `docker run -it dziugasiot/wintekaiot:firsttry bash` ( create a container )

Comment: Okay, let's try it. I get my image id - dziugasiot/wintekaiot, firsttry, bd516aa1ab02, 2 hours ago. Then I do `docker pull dziugasiot/wintekaiot:firsttry`, and after I launch `docker run dziugasiot/wintekaiot:firsttry bash,` the container creates, but when I launch it, it just exists instantly

Comment: Exits instantly because bash itself exits with empty input. You should try `docker run -it dziugasiot/wintekaiot:firsttry bash` . With -it switches you tell docker runtime that you want to attach an interactive terminal to your process, so it will switch your prompt to the containers prompt.

Answer (score 1):

All "files" (layers) needed to create a container for that image are already downloaded, see the message "Status: Image is up to date for dziugasiot/wintekaiot:firsttry"

Docker uses copy-on-write mechanism, so in short: once you download an image, you don't have to download it again (for the same version).

For beginners with Docker I don't recommend to do anything in Docker root folder, but for a complete answer: you can find your image files (layers) in Docker root folder. The place and the format of it depends on your actual configuration, but you can look it up by issuing `docker info` command and looking for Docker Root.